# How can I change the style of a form's field label?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am programming a form with sencha that should change the mandatory fields depending on which fields are already filled.

I have a listener on those fields, but I cannot change their style in it.

Any advices?

Thank you!

Comment: What you tried? Better if you can post some sample code.

Comment: An example would indeed be helpful. Couldn't you manage to apply style in the event handler as follows? function assignedListener(){ this.style.backgroundColor = "red"; this.classList.add("myClass"); } Please look at the current style and see if it uses "!important" or whatever inline style.

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked with addClass("myClass")
Sorry I didn't show any code but it is part from a really big app and it wouldn't help too much.

Comment: Can you please post some code on how its achieved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! It worked with `addClass("myClass")`. Sorry I didn't show any code but it is part from a really big app and it wouldn't help too much.